# In which DNS zone files i have to put spf record entry to get "spf=pass"?

Tags: spf

> "Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 46.23.76.174 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of vns6.wtech.in) smtp.mail=a@vns6.wtech.in".

This is the result when I get after seeing the mail sent from my mail server to gmail so I want to turn `spf=neutral` to `spf=pass`

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Also I want to know in which zone file of dns I have to put my `spf record` entry?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/364777/spf-record-entry

Answer (score 2):

In the DNS server which is primarily authoritative for `wtech.in`, which seems to be either ENOW.MERCURY.ORDERBOX-DNS.COM, ENOW.VENUS.ORDERBOX-DNS.COM, ENOW.EARTH.ORDERBOX-DNS.COM, or ENOW.MARS.ORDERBOX-DNS.COM, you need to put a TXT record that looks something like this:

```
vns6  IN    TXT "v=spf1 ip4:46.23.76.174 -all"
```

That will tell google (and everyone else) that the address 46.23.76.174 is explicitly permitted to send email from the domain `vns6.wtech.in`, and that noone else is.  Be sure that's the result you want **before** you advertise such a record.

Comment: ok i will do as you told and update ypu.

Comment: can you tell me where in the DNS server i have to put this entry.

Comment: In the zonefile for the domain wtech.in .

Comment: ya but i dont know where to find this file in the dns server and what is the name of this file.

Comment: @AchalTomar, Seriously, I told you this already in your other question.  I suspect your DNS is being hosted by your registrar.  Go look in the web interface where you got your DNS.

Comment: @zoredache my dns is entirely in my control and the zone files can be accessed by me,that is why i am asking about their location in bind.

Comment: Well they would be in whatever zone file you put them in.  Start by lookin in the named.conf, and any files included by the named conf on each of the 4 `ORDERBOX-DNS.COM` servers.  You do run those as well right?

Comment: yes i do run those servers thanks for your help  "Zoredache",i got answer to my question.

Comment: primarily authoritative is defined in SOA RR of domain: `[SOA] enow.mars.orderbox-dns.com.`